# JavaScript displaying content

Tags: javascript

I want to make script which display text when somebody choose option from select.
I was trying this script but it's wasn't work.

```
<select name="inputDrugForm">
    <option id="one">Tabletki</option>
    <option id="two">Syrop</option>
    <option id="one">Saszetki</option>
    <option id="two">Spray</option>
    <option id="one">Inny</option>
 </select><br>
 <div id="content"></div>

        <script type="text/javascript">
        var b1 = document.getElementById('one'),
            b2 = document.getElementById('two'),
            content = document.getElementById('content');

        b1.onselect = function() {
            content.innerHTML = 'text one';
        }

        b2.onselect = function() {
            content.innerHTML = 'text two';
        }
        </script>
```

Comment: It's `onchange`, not `onselect`.

Comment: you are doing it wrong, you have to assign values to the options, and use onchange event on whole select not on options separately, then read the value of it in that event to know what was selected

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow some basic step to implement select

1)create select element in a proper way to add options with valid values

```
<select id="inputDrugForm">
  <option value="Tabletki">Tabletki</option>
<option value="Syrop">Syrop</option>
<option value="Saszetki">Saszetki</option>
<option value="Spray">Spray</option>
<option value="Inny">Inny</option>
</select>
```

2)add change event for select element

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        var b1 = document.getElementById('inputDrugForm'),
            content = document.getElementById('content');

        b1.onchange = function(e) {

            content.innerHTML = e.target.value;
        }
</script>
```

other option you can add change event in the select element directly

Answer (score 1):

`id` attr is not used on `option` element !!!

**simple example :**

```js
        var b = document.getElementById('inputDrug'),
            content = document.getElementById('content');

        b.onchange = function() {
            content.innerHTML = b.value;
        }
```

```html
<select name="inputDrugForm" id="inputDrug">
    <option value="one">Tabletki</option>
    <option value="two">Syrop</option>
    <option value="one">Saszetki</option>
    <option value="two">Spray</option>
    <option value="one">Inny</option>
 </select><br>
 <div id="content"></div>
```

Comment: not sure if it's what op was asking for, I guess he wanted to categorize products, that's why there is "one", "two", "one", "two"

Comment: then it must use the `if` condition.

Comment: not really, can assign `values` to options like this `<option value="one" ...` and the rest will be the same

Answer (score 0):

```
<select id="MySelect" onchange="myFunction()">
   <option value="one">Tabletki</option>
   <option value="two">Syrop</option>
   <option value="one">Saszetki</option>
   <option value="two">Spray</option>
   <option value="one">Inny</option>
</select>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var x = document.getElementById("mySelect").value;
  document.getElementById("content").innerHTML = "You selected: " + x;
}
</script>
```